Creating cascading drop-down lists using related tables/layers in QGIS
I have three tables/layers:

'places' (a table with geometry)
'places_types' (a standalone table)
and 'classes' (also a standalone table)

There is a many-to-one relationship between the 'places' and 'places_types' tables, with places.places_type_id acting as a foreign key referencing places_types.places_type_id.
Similarly, the relationship between 'places_types' and 'classes' is many-to-one (places_types.class_id is a foreign key referencing classes.class_id).
The Value Relation widget is not an option as it requires the places table to have two fields (with values for types and corresponding classes), which is not the case.
